# Quartz Plugin for Grails - OutOfMemoryError in the Production environment

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler, cloud-foundry

I am trying to deploy my Grails 2.1.1 application to cloudfoundry.com. On my local computer the application runs without problems. When removing the Quartz plugin dependency from the BuildConfig.groovy I'am able to start the application on cloudfoundry successfully.

Dependency:

```
compile ":quartz:1.0-RC5"
```

The grails cf-logs prints the following error:

```
Exception in thread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

Below see my Job:

```
package de.tum.wi.fm.game
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext

class StartGameJob {
    def execute(JobExecutionContext context) {
        def gameRoundId = context.mergedJobDataMap.get('gameRoundId')

        if(gameRoundId) {
            GameRound gameRound = GameRound.get(gameRoundId)
            if(gameRound) {
                Game game = gameRound?.game
                game.currentGameRound = gameRound
                game.save(flush: true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The trigger is placed in a service:

```
def jobParams = [gameRoundId:gameRound.id]
Date gameRoundEndDate = gameRound.endDate.toDate()
ChangeRoundJob.schedule(gameRoundEndDate, jobParams)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OutOfMemoryError exception determines that the JVM hasn't enough memory assigned. You need  to increase the memory of cloudfoundry instance and consequently increase memory of the JVM.

Try to execute following commands when deploying your application:

```
grails -Dgrails.env=production cf-push --memory=2048 --no-start
grails -Dgrails.env=production cf-env-add JAVA_OPTS -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
grails -Dgrails.env=production cf-start
```

The first command will push (deploy) the application into the cloudfoundry instance and doesn't start it.

The second will set JVM environment variables, sufficient memory settings.

Third command starts the application.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried assigning more memory to the application? You can do this using VMC;

```
vmc scale [application name]
```

Follow the prompts and VMC should ask how much memory you wish to assign.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that and have assigned 2G of Memory but without any change. Do these settings influence the -Xms and -Xmx params of the JVM? Maybe assigning more memory to these params would help.